# Ubuntu 14.04 PHP PECL Oauth error

Tags: php, ubuntu, oauth, quickbooks-online

Trying to integrate a PHP application with Quickbooks and the Quickbooks SDK says it needs PECL Oauth.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and get this error when I try to install Oauth.

```
sudo pecl install oauth
downloading oauth-1.2.3.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.2.3.tgz (45,531 bytes)
.............done: 45,531 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-  download/oauth-1.2.3.tgz"
Download of "pecl/oauth" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/oauth"
Download failed 
install failed
```

I Googled a bit and updated my system:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
```

but no luck there.  Any ideas - this should be an easy step for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-oauth
```

Comment: Worked for php 7 : sudo apt-get install php7.1-oauth

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-oauth` will choose the right version for you.

Comment: ... and `sudo systemctl reload apache2`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-oauth` for php 7. You should explicitly say which PHP version to use in case you have multiple PHPs

Answer (score 3):

I am also using the QuickBooks API and for PHP 7 this worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.0-dev
sudo pecl install oauth
```

Then add to your php.ini

```
extension=oauth.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this resolve the problem:

```
sudo pecl install oauth-1.2.3
```